# Ruby Mechanize Clicking Not Working

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, automation, nokogiri, mechanize

Here's the scraping part of my code right now

```
while counter <= 3
  url = "http://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=" << job_title_search << "&l=" << job_location << ",+ON&start=" << (counter * 20).to_s
  counter += 1
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

  # can't put in if loop to only perform once for some reason
  page = agent.get(url)

  current_page = agent.page.uri
  puts current_page

  doc.css(".result").each do |item|
    job_title = item.at_css(".jobtitle").text[/[^\s][a-zA-Z -]*/]
    job_company = item.at_css(".company").text[/[^\s][a-zA-Z -]*/]
    full_job = job_title + " - " + job_company

    agent.current_page.link_with(:class => '.jobtitle').click
    posting_page = agent.page.uri
    puts posting_page

    if cache.include?(full_job) == false
      cache << full_job
      puts "#{job_title} - #{job_company}"
    end
  end

  puts ""
end
```

I know for a fact that the '.jobtitle' class exists, because the part that returns the position title works fine. What I'm trying to figure out is why Mechanize is not allowing me to use the 'click' function. In other tests I've done on the wikipedia main page, it works fine on CSS IDs, classes, & text.

So my question is what is causing it to fail on the click function? The error it generates is the generic "undefined method 'click' for nil:NilClass".

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells us that the object you're calling the `click` method on is `nil`. You call `click` here:

```
agent.current_page.link_with(:class => '.jobtitle').click
```

...so we can infer that your call to `link_with` is returning `nil`.

I would presume that this is failing because your page doesn't have a link with a `class` attribute equal to `.jobtitle`. Rather, your page probably has a link with a `class` attribute equal to `jobtitle`. And so:

```
agent.current_page.link_with(:class => 'jobtitle').click
```

Comment: I thought that too at first, but it's not that (just tried it again to make sure I'm not going nuts) because I'm accessing the '.jobtitle' class earlier in the script.

Comment: '.jobtitle' is the css selector, 'jobtitle' is the class (or part of it).